# Dependencies from git

Tags: asp.net-core, kpm

I'm playing a bit with the new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity but the 3.0.0-beta2 looks very different from the current state of affairs in git. I'd like to build against he git version.

I seem to remember hearing that it possible to reference a git repository directly from the dependencies in project.json. How does one do that? What's the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Instead of using the [NuGet feed](https://nuget.org/api/v2/), switch to the [Nightly feed on MyGet](https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2). We produce builds on every checkin from the code in Git. The latest versions on the MyGet feed are `beta4-*`
2. Clone the repo and use global.json to point to the sources, as described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx)

Adding a reference directly to a Git repo without cloning it beforehand is not supported.